# SQL how to assign CASE under SELECT query to a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL SELECT query.

```
SELECT  STOCK
    ,QTY*PRICE AS 'TOTAL'
    ,(QTY*PRICE)*RATE AS 'VALUATION'
    ,((QTY*PRICE)*RATE)+1 AS 'ADD_VALUATION'
    ,CASE WHEN GRP = 'A' THEN  100 - isnull(LDP_A,0)
     WHEN GRP = 'B' THEN  100 - isnull(LDP_B,0)
     WHEN GRP = 'C' THEN  100 - isnull(LDP_C,0)
     -- TO Z
     END AS 'LDP'
     ,(((QTY*PRICE)*RATE)+1) 
        / 
        (CASE WHEN GRP = 'A' THEN  100 - isnull(LDP_A,0)
        WHEN GRP = 'B' THEN  100 - isnull(LDP_B,0)
        WHEN GRP = 'C' THEN  100 - isnull(LDP_C,0)
        -- TO Z
        END) * RATE AS HTC
FROM STOCKBL
```

Is there a way to clean this redundancy of statements? How can I assign the CASE to a variable so I can replace this with more neat code.

Comment: Is this for mysql or sql server?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos it's SQL server. apologies

Comment: what is GRP in case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT  STOCK
       ,t2.TOTAL AS 'TOTAL'
       ,t2.TOTAL*RATE AS 'VALUATION'
       ,(t2.TOTAL*RATE)+1 AS 'ADD_VALUATION'
       ,t1.LDP AS 'LDP'
       ,((t2.TOTAL*RATE)+1) / t1.LDP * RATE AS HTC
FROM STOCKBL
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT CASE 
             WHEN GRP = 'A' THEN  100 - isnull(LDP_A,0)
             WHEN GRP = 'B' THEN  100 - isnull(LDP_B,0)
             WHEN GRP = 'C' THEN  100 - isnull(LDP_C,0)
             -- TO Z
          END AS LDP) AS t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT QTY*PRICE AS TOTAL) AS t2
```

Comment: This is what I want. Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CTE or subquery as below:

```
;with cte as 
(
SELECT  STOCK
    ,QTY*PRICE AS 'TOTAL'
    ,(QTY*PRICE)*RATE AS 'VALUATION'
    ,CASE WHEN GRP = 'A' THEN  100 - isnull(LDP_A,0)
     WHEN GRP = 'B' THEN  100 - isnull(LDP_B,0)
     WHEN GRP = 'C' THEN  100 - isnull(LDP_C,0)
     -- TO Z
     END AS 'LDP'
     , RATE
FROM STOCKBL
)
SELECT Stock, total, Valuation, Valuation + 1 as  'ADD_VALUATION',
        ( (Valuation+1)/ LDP) * Rate ) as HTC from cte
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response